# Load saved key data to UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

This is my code for adding names to the table:

```
@IBAction func addButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        mineSpillere.append(namesTextBox.text)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

This is my "mineSpillere":

```
var mineSpillere = [String]()
```

This is my code for saving the key:

```
func saveKey(){
        println("saving key")

        var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(mineSpillere, forKey: "spillereKey")
        defaults.synchronize()

        println(mineSpillere)
    }
```

This is my viewDidLoad code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.x

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(spillereKey) != nil) {
        if let testArray : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(spillereKey) {
            var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString]
            println(readArray)
        }
    }

    self.myTableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

This is my code for loading the key:

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("spillereKey") != nil) {
            if let testArray : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("spillereKey") {
                var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString]
                println(readArray)
            }
        }
```

The "println(readArray)", gives me an output in the console that looks like this:

> ["erik", "tom", "phil"]

This is my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = self.mineSpillere[indexPath.row]

        return cell;
    }
```

How can i add in the "viewDidLoad" that the key load it´s data into the tableView?  I have saved table data into a key using NSUserDefaults. I want to write that data to the UITableView when opening the view controller(viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would not have to use the reload command but under certain circumstances it may be appropriate.

self.tableView?.reload()

Comment: That does not do what i am asking for.. I have saved table data into a key using NSUserDefaults. I want to write that data to the UITableView when opening the view controller(viewDidLoad). How do i do that?